# How can I change x-scale for ggplot in R?

Tags: r

I have "date" column and the values are from 1900 to 2020.

When I plot geom_line, how can I make x-scale showing only 2000, 2005, 2010, 2015, 2020 ?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You normally control this with a scale,  eg scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date("2000-1-1"), as.Date("2020-1-1")), date_minor_breaks = "1 year"). Try adding this to your plot. Hope this helps!

Comment: or maybe date_breaks = "1 year"